# Get `Use of expired sessions is not permitted` error when using client session on mongodb nodejs application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My mongodb is 3.6 and my nodejs application is using mongo client 3.0. Below is the source code to use mongo client session to ensure causal relationship:

```
const session = client.startSession();
  const col = client.db('test').collection('test');
  col
    .insert({a: true}, {w: 0, j: false, session})
    .then(() => {
      return col.count({session});
    })
    .then(ret => {
      console.log(ret);
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
  session.endSession();
}
```

I got below errors when running this application. It works without specifying the session for the `insert` or `count` command. I wonder how I can use session in this case.

```
    { MongoError: Use of expired sessions is not permitted
    at executeOperation (/Users/joey/dev/mongodb/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:390:13)
    at Collection.count (/Users/joey/dev/mongodb/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1889:10)
    at col.insert.then (/Users/joey/dev/mongodb/demo/index.js:33:18)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Use of expired sessions is not permitted' }
```

Answer (score 10):

I think I found out what wrong with my code. I need to move `session.endSession();` to the then or catch since it is a promise call.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I found and it explains your issue clearly.

> Mongoose and the MongoDB node driver encourages the use of a global variable to connect once to the database during the lifetime of the application, and discourage the practice of connect-disconnect for every operation. This is because the MongoDB driver keeps a connection pool and will create/reuse connections as needed. Note that this is the reason why the connection object is a global object in Mongoose.

You can check this URL (source) for details:
[MongoExpiredSessionError](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongoerror-cannot-use-a-session-that-has-ended/8832)